# How to slow down scroll speed using TouchAction()

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

I want to scroll through a recycler view in android. I am using TouchAction to scroll.

```
getToucAction().press(511, 1200).moveTo(0, -450).release().perform();
```

But the problem is, scrolling is too fast and i am not able to grab any specific element in the list.
Can any one suggest any work around.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `waitAction` method to slow down the actions.

E.g.

```
getTouchAction()
    .press(511, 1200)
    .waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    .moveTo(0, -450)
    .release()
    .perform();
```